# Why do I see a "Firefox" button on Firefox 28?

Tags: 13.10, firefox, browser

I noticed that recently the "Firefox" button appears again in my Firefox 28, even with Global Menu installed. This is really back or is something wrong with my Firefox on Ubuntu 13.10?

[image]
[image]

Comment: "appears again" when wasn't it there? What version (of Ubuntu & Firefox) are you using? What adds-on do you have enabled?

Comment: I really don't remember, I think it was on Firefox 28 update. Ubuntu 13.10, Firefox 28.

Comment: I already tried to deactivate all add-ons, nothing change. Do you have this same button on your Firefox?

Comment: No, I don't. In fact, I have never seen that icon. What happen when you press it? Take a screen shoot with the results.

Comment: I just added another picture. It's just the menu button, just like the old "Firefox button", it exist before the global menu support. I just installed the Firefox from nightlies (firefox-trunk), and it doesn't have this menu button

Answer (score 0):

Disable all Ubuntu extensions and restart Firefox, then you can disable the Firefox button (enable the "menu bar" by right clicking on the tabs bar) and enable the extensions again.